# Androidplot - background and ranges

Tags: android, androidplot

I'm new to that library. I'm trying to Create the following plot:

[image]

Meanwhile I have the next one:

[image]

***My questions:***   NOTE: The colors doesn't matters

1. How do I get rid of the black area (where was lables on range domain and title)
   and center the plot (like in the first picture)
2. How to add ranges as in the first picture ?  (x:[1-7] y:[0-4500])
3. Make the same grid as in the first picture

**My code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private XYPlot mySimpleXYPlot;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 // Create a couple arrays of y-values to plot:
    Number[] days =   { 1  , 2   , 3   , 4   , 5   , 6   , 7 };
    Number[] values = { 380, 1433, 1965, 3200, 3651, 3215, 3217 };

    // initialize our XYPlot reference:
    mySimpleXYPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);
    mySimpleXYPlot.getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setBorderStyle(XYPlot.BorderStyle.NONE, null, null);
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);



    // Domain
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelPaint(null);
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainOriginLinePaint(null);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, days.length);     
    mySimpleXYPlot.setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));


    //Range
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().setRangeOriginLinePaint(null);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setRangeStep(XYStepMode.SUBDIVIDE, values.length);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setRangeValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));


    //Remove legend
    mySimpleXYPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mySimpleXYPlot.getLegendWidget());
    mySimpleXYPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mySimpleXYPlot.getDomainLabelWidget());
    mySimpleXYPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mySimpleXYPlot.getRangeLabelWidget());
    mySimpleXYPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mySimpleXYPlot.getTitleWidget());

    // Turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
            Arrays.asList(days),          
            Arrays.asList(values), 
            "Series1");                             // Set the display title of the series

    // Create a formatter to use for drawing a series using LineAndPointRenderer:
    LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(
            Color.rgb(0, 200, 0),                   // line color
            Color.rgb(0, 100, 0),                   // point color
            Color.CYAN);                            // fill color 

 // setup our line fill paint to be a slightly transparent gradient:
    Paint lineFill = new Paint();
    lineFill.setAlpha(200);
    lineFill.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 250, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));

    series1Format.setFillPaint(lineFill);

    // add a new series' to the xyplot:
    mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

    // by default, AndroidPlot displays developer guides to aid in laying out your plot.
    // To get rid of them call disableAllMarkup():
    mySimpleXYPlot.disableAllMarkup();
}

}
```

Comment: I am trying to find out how you removed the x-axis lines from the grid in your incomplete one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I hope this is helpful.

My code:

```
private XYPlot mySimpleXYPlot;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create a couple arrays of y-values to plot:
    Number[] days =   { 1  , 2   , 3   , 4   , 5   , 6   , 7 };
    Number[] values = { 380, 1433, 1965, 3200, 3651, 3215, 3217 };

    // initialize our XYPlot reference:
    mySimpleXYPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);

    mySimpleXYPlot.setBorderStyle(Plot.BorderStyle.NONE, null, null);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setPlotMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setPlotPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setGridPadding(0, 10, 5, 0);

    mySimpleXYPlot.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    mySimpleXYPlot.position(
            mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget(),
            0,
            XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_LEFT,
            0,
            YLayoutStyle.RELATIVE_TO_CENTER,
            AnchorPosition.LEFT_MIDDLE);

    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);

    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);

    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginLabelPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginLinePaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginLinePaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);

    // Domain
    mySimpleXYPlot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, days.length);     
    mySimpleXYPlot.setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));
    mySimpleXYPlot.setDomainStepValue(1);

    //Range
    mySimpleXYPlot.setRangeBoundaries(0, 4500, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setRangeStepValue(10);
    //mySimpleXYPlot.setRangeStep(XYStepMode.SUBDIVIDE, values.length);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setRangeValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));

    //Remove legend
    mySimpleXYPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mySimpleXYPlot.getLegendWidget());
    mySimpleXYPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mySimpleXYPlot.getDomainLabelWidget());
    mySimpleXYPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mySimpleXYPlot.getRangeLabelWidget());
    mySimpleXYPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mySimpleXYPlot.getTitleWidget());

    // Turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
            Arrays.asList(days),          
            Arrays.asList(values), 
            "Series1");                             // Set the display title of the series

    // Create a formatter to use for drawing a series using LineAndPointRenderer:
    LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(
            Color.rgb(0, 200, 0),                   // line color
            Color.rgb(0, 100, 0),                   // point color
            Color.CYAN);                            // fill color 

 // setup our line fill paint to be a slightly transparent gradient:
    Paint lineFill = new Paint();
    lineFill.setAlpha(200);
    lineFill.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 250, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));

    series1Format.setFillPaint(lineFill);

    // add a new series' to the xyplot:
    mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

    // by default, AndroidPlot displays developer guides to aid in laying out your plot.
    // To get rid of them call disableAllMarkup():
    mySimpleXYPlot.disableAllMarkup();
}
```

}

It will look like this:

[image: graph]

Comment: Hey i want to plot a graph that looks like this

Comment: Is this possible like this data:image/png;base64,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

Answer (score 12):

In the latest version, instead of using

```
 mySimpleXYPlot.position(
        mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget(),
        0,
        XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_LEFT,
        0,
        YLayoutStyle.RELATIVE_TO_CENTER,
        AnchorPosition.LEFT_MIDDLE);
```

it is to be used:

```
 mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().setSize(new SizeMetrics(
            0, SizeLayoutType.FILL,
            0, SizeLayoutType.FILL));
```

This will eliminate the black area.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for new Devices:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    plot.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create a formatter to use for drawing a series using LineAndPointRenderer:
LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(
        Color.rgb(0, 200, 0),                   // line color
        Color.rgb(0, 100, 0),                   // point color
        Color.CYAN);
```

Argument is missing

It should be like this

```
// Create a formatter to use for drawing a series using LineAndPointRenderer:
LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 200, 0),Color.rgb(0, 100, 0),Color.CYAN, new PointLabelFormatter());
```